# How to restore core_confg_data in magento

Tags: mysql, sql, core-config-data

I deleted the core_confg_data and now I can't access my magento store, does anyone know how to re install it or recover it ? I am already trying for several hours...

Comment: Do you have a backup of the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing a new Magento and copy it from the new DB and change the secure and unsecure url. You might be lucky enough and the site might be back up.
[Here](http://jpst.it/j44J) is mines from a new installation from a couple of days ago.